# Raycasts are not detecting objects with assigned layer in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to use raycasts to detect walls with specific layer, but it just doesn't detect anything. I have previously tried using raycasts for detecting ground and it also didn't work.

Code I tried first was:

```
    private void CheckForWall()
    {
        wallRight = Physics.Raycast(transform.position, orientation.right, out rightWallhit, wallCheckDistance, whatIsWall);
        wallLeft = Physics.Raycast(transform.position, -orientation.right, out rightWallhit, wallCheckDistance, whatIsWall);
    }
```

with wallCheckDistance being public float set to 0.7 and what is wall being LayerMask whatIsWall set to walls I want to wallrun on. I am sure the problem is detecting since I also have state handler showing different states and wallrunning never comes up. After cranking up the wallCheckDistance to 1.5, I was able to wallrun only on side of one wall out of many.